# How to add radio buttons to an existing calculator format

Tags: java, swing

I have the buttons for the calculator all layed out but I need to add radio buttons on the left hand side in order to let user choose to what they want to convert the number. The options are hexa, octa, dec, and binary. the died wher the numbers are shown ill do later. Thanks for any help and your time.

Here's the code what I have so far

```
public class CalculatorBuild extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    public CalculatorBuild() {
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridLayout Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 4));
        frame.add(new JButton("A"));
        frame.add(new JButton(""));
        frame.add(new JButton(""));
        frame.add(new JButton(""));
        frame.add(new JButton(""));
        frame.add(new JButton("B"));
        frame.add(new JButton("<-"));
        frame.add(new JButton("CE"));
        frame.add(new JButton("c"));
        frame.add(new JButton("%"));
        frame.add(new JButton("C"));
        frame.add(new JButton("7"));
        frame.add(new JButton("8"));
        frame.add(new JButton("9"));
        frame.add(new JButton("+"));
        frame.add(new JButton("D"));
        frame.add(new JButton("4"));
        frame.add(new JButton("5"));
        frame.add(new JButton("6"));
        frame.add(new JButton("-"));
        frame.add(new JButton("E"));
        frame.add(new JButton("1"));
        frame.add(new JButton("2"));
        frame.add(new JButton("3"));
        frame.add(new JButton("*"));
        frame.add(new JButton("F"));
        frame.add(new JButton("."));
        frame.add(new JButton("0"));
        frame.add(new JButton("+/-"));
        frame.add(new JButton("="));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // listener code

    }
}
```

Comment: should be tagged `swing`

Comment: also not related to your question, but you could put all the strings in an array, iterate through them with a for-loop, and add a button for each, massively reducing lines of code.

Comment: Create two panels, one for your existing buttons and one for your radio buttons, layout these buttons together, probably using a `BorderLayout`

Answer (score 1):

[Here is Oracle's tutorial on radio buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#radiobutton).

As far as your specific case goes, this is what you could try:

```
JRadioButton hexa = new JRadioButton("hexa");
hexa.setSelected(true);

// Make some more buttons here.

ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
bg.add(hexa);
// Add the other buttons.
```

Also, I would recommend creating a JPanel to add all your buttons to. Then you add the JPanel to the JFrame. [There is an Oracle tutorial for this here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html#contentpane) which also covers the content pane.